# Angular NGRS State for Key and Value of Array type

Tags: angular, ngrx

Can someone please help in creating state and reducer methods for below sample JSON structure.
Let's say I have below Json data where I can have marks for physics, chemistry and social.

Student will have an array for above three subjects and marks scored.

```
{
  "John": [
    {
      "physics": "55"
    },
    {
      "chemistry": "88"
    },
    {
      "social": "90"
    }
  ],
  "James": [
    {
      "physics": "55"
    },
    {
      "chemistry": "45"
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe NGRX State will be in below format.

```
export interface Score {
  physics: string;
  chemistry: string;
  social: string;
}

export interface IScoreState {
  [studentName: string]: Score;
}
```

How to write reducer methods for

1. Inserting a new entry -> Peter with Physics, chemistry and social each 35 marks.
2. How to insert marks for existing student -> how to enter social 45 marks for Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you the answer for the reducer without any other library apart ngrx.

Into actions file add:

```
export const scoreSetMarksToStudent = createAction(
  "[SCORE] SetMarkToStudenSubject",
  props<{ student: string; marks: Score }>()
);
export const scoreSetMarkToStudentSubject = createAction(
  "[SCORE] SetMarkToStudenSubject",
  props<{ student: string; subject: string; marks: number }>()
);
```

In your reducer file add:

```
const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(scoreSetMarksToStudent, (state, { student, marks }) => { // answer 1
    return {
      ...state,
      [state[student]: {
        ...marks
      }
    }
  }),
  on(scoreSetMarkToStudentSubject, (state, { student, subject, mark }) => { // answer 2
    return {
      ...state,
      [state[student]: {
        ...state[student],
        [subject]: mark
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please tell me how to delete entry and a subject. Similar to above how to write for deleting entry and a subject. Thanks in advance